# ASP.NET MVC : redirect to action using URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can we redirect to a particular action using `System.Uri`

```
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
    Uri url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer; 

    if (condition)
    {
        return View(url);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

i want to redirect the page to `url`

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `Redirect()` method which takes an url.

The trick is to convert it to a `string` first as the `Redirect()` method do not take an `Uri` object:

```
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel )
{
    Uri url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer; 

    if (condition)
    {
        return Redirect(url.ToString());
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx)